# What is the source of "VishvAdhiko Rudro Maharshi" (विश्वाधिको रुद्रो महर्षिः)?

Tags: scripture, mantras, sanskrit, source, shruti

I'm finding Source for "VishvAdhiko Rudro Maharshi" Mantra.

> विश्वाधिको रुद्रो महर्षिः 
>  
> VishvAdhiko Rudro Maharshi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taittariya Aranyaka of Krishna Yajurveda (10.12) contains this mantra:

> **यो देवानां प्रथमं पुरस्ताद्विश्वाधिको रुद्रो महर्षिः** । 
> हिरण्यगर्भं पश्यत जायमानꣳ स नो देवः शुभयास्मृत्या संयुनक्तु ॥ *(Taittariya Aranyaka 10.12)*

This mantra is also quoted in Shwetashwatara Upanishad 3.4 with slight variation:

> यो देवानां प्रभवश्चोद्भवश्च **विश्वाधिपो रुद्रो महर्षिः** । 
> हिरण्यगर्भं जनयामास पूर्वंस नो बुद्ध्या शुभया संयुनक्तु ॥ ४॥ 
> He, the omniscient Rudra, the creator of the gods and the bestower of their powers, the support of the universe, He who, in the beginning, gave birth to Hiranyagarbha-may He endow us with clear intellect!

Similarly, in Bhasma Jabala Upanishad also [Lord Shiva speaks](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/why-is-lord-shiva-called-soma/50583#50583):

> विश्वं भूतं भुवनं चित्रं
> बहुधा जातं जायमानं च यत्सर्वस्य सोमोऽहमेव
> जनिता **विश्वाधिको रुद्रो महर्षिः** । *(Bhasma Jabala Upanishad)* 
> I, Soma, am the creator of various worlds, past, present, and future. I, Rudra the great seer transcending all, see the Brahma and other created beings.